# How do I add background to an anchor tag?

Tags: html, css, background

I need to create an anchor tag, which says "RSS" and there should be an icon next to that text (left-side), added as a background in CSS. The icon is png, 32x32px.

HTML:

```
<a href="" class="rss-icon">RSS</a>
```

CSS:

```
   .rss-icon{ 
    padding-left: 40px; 
    line-height: 32px; 
    background: url(rss.png) left;  
    }
```

But this is not working for me. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: **maybe your url path is wrong/ it may be overridden somewhere**, working for me http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/RdZvw/ so I have voted to close your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
.rss-icon{ 
    padding-left: 40px; 
    line-height: 32px; 
    background-color:#cccccc;  
    }
```

working correctly.. may be URL to the pic is different.